# How do I use Data Validation to accept a value based on value in another cell on the same row?

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image]

As we can see from the image, I want to accept value in `Column B` based on the value in `Column A`. For example, if the value in cell `A2` is "India" then cell `B2` should accept only "Delhi". This is the only condition.

How do I do this using Data validation?

Comment: `=IF(A2="India",B2="Delhi")` is the formula in this case :)

Comment: It's called dependent or cascading drop-down lists. There are a few different ways to approach it. The [first hit on Google](http://www.excel-university.com/create-depdendent-drop-downs-conditional-data-validation/) has a pretty good summary of the common methods.

Comment: @EngineerToast, I don't want to define the list. I just want to have the conditions in the formula.

Comment: @DirkReichel, Could you please let me know how do I apply that formula for the entire column instead of hard coding A2 and B2? Thanks!

Comment: If there is *exactly* one allowable City for each Country, then why not just use a formula instead of data validation? If there are more than 7 countries, it won't work in Excel 2003 (later versions can handle 64). If there are many countries and / or cities, your formulas are going to get *very* messy.

Comment: @EngineerToast No, It is not only one allowable city for each country. The condition is only for specific country. If user enters A2 as "India" and B2 as anything other than "Delhi" then we should error to the user. I am sorry for not making myself clear in the question.

Comment: No, you were clear. I just assumed that your actual data was more complicated than your example. To do exactly what you asked, Dirk's comment will take care of it. If your actual data is more complex, the answer will be more complex.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35134/discussion-between-javanoob-and-engineer-toast).